# Add individual page titles to html document head in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

For SEO reasons I want to add individual page titles to my web pages instead of general site name as it is done by default.

Here is what I have figured out by myself:

I need to copy to my theme and modify `Document.cshtml` section:

`<title>@Html.Title(title, siteName)</title>`

I need to insert there `Title` content part that is included in every page.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [module](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.EMS.PageTitleOverride/1.0) that does exactly what I need!

Comment: for anyone seeing this now, it no longer works, sadly.

Answer (score 4):

From your view, do this:

```
@{
    Html.TitleForPage("Mr1159pm's Page Title");
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how to use it. Maybe I should be more precise in my question. I want Orchard to dynamically get content item's Title and place it in the header's title section of the page. So for example for content type `Page` I want it to get the page's title and place it in the header title and I want it to be done dynamically for every page and other content types that have `Title' field

Comment: Something like this: `Html.TitleForPage(Model.As<TitlePart>().Title);`. You should add some null checks in there in case the Model isn't a Content Item / is null / doesn't have a Title part / etc.

Comment: Thanks! And in what files should I include this? Where are they located? Sorry, but I am really new to Orchard and ASP.NET.

Comment: I get the error saying that TitlePart is not defined. Should I add some using statement? If so what should it be?

Comment: Not every content item has a TitlePart, and some pages can have more than one ContentItem. Also, the "Model" at the Document.cshtml level is a Layout shape, not a ContentItem, so it's most likely not going to work like this. You should be doing this individually for your content items. For example, in the (fictional) template for my "Shoes" content type, I'd have this: `
    Html.TitleForPage(new string[] {Model.Name, "Shoes", "Shoes Shopping Guide"});`. You could also do `
    Html.TitleForPage(new string[] {Model.As<TitlePart>().Title}, "YourWebsiteName.com"});`

Comment: I really don't know how to use it. Can you tell me specifically for page content type what code I need to add and in what file (file name and folder) to change meta page title for page and I should be able to figure out from that concrete example what to do with other content types. Sorry to be such pain but I need a specific example.